# Tracking individual request progresses in ASINetworkQueue

Tags: iphone, background, download, asihttprequest

I needed to download some files when buttons on tableViewCells are clicked.

I was thinking of adding them to an ASINetworkQueue so that the download can happen.
However, when I came to tracking progress, it appears to me that they are saying that I can have only ONE PROGRESS for the ENTIRE QUEUE.

Is this true, or is there a way that I can track the progress of each request individually?
I need to have a custom tableview which shows how much of each file has been downloaded.

also, on a not-so-related note, can i set the

```
[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
```

for requests INSIDE the network queue?
I need to have support for background downloading, and if networkqueue does not support it, i might as well chuck the idea right now and look for some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) mentions:

> Each ASIHTTPRequest has two delegates
>   that can be used for tracking progress
>   - downloadProgressDelegate (for downloads) and uploadProgressDelegate
>   (for uploads).

You can still use these delegates on the request, even if the request is part of a queue.

The network queue is just driven by events coming from the requests themselves (and the requests continue to be part of the queue even if they're running in the background). I believe that if you mark the requests to continue in the background then the queue events will continue too.

Comment: Thanks!
But when i used the downloadProgressDelegate and assigned it to a UIProgressVIew control, i could only get like a percentage completion.
How do i get the info like 3mb/ 21mb Done?

Comment: The downloadProgressDelegate gets the information you need to display 3mb/21mb - you'll need to create a custom view to show exactly what you want; if you're not sure how try asking as a new question.

Comment: Thanks. After some poking around, I got it to work. What i needed was the
[request setDidRecieveDataSelector:....]
In this, i used the request.totalBytesRead and request.contentLength.
I had to cast them to floats to get the divides to work properly, but worked in the end. :)

Comment: @JosephH
I am having trouble with DidReceiveDataSelector. It is not downloading to a file when i use this, though I can make custom strings with "3248Kb / 4993Kb Done" and such...
Is there a way I can use downloadProgessDelegate to do the same thing, so that my setDownloadPath isnt affected?
setDownloadProgressDelegate accepted only 1 argument and that was my UIProgressView. Dont know how i could get Kbs downloaded from that. :(

Comment: @mvishnu Set the progress delegate to be your own class and implement the request:didReceiveBytes: method (and make it call UIProgressView setProgress). Or subclass UIProgress view and implement request:didReceiveBytes: in your subclass.

Comment: @mvishnu hi, me too having same issue with showing the download progress on a UIProgressView, if you have got the solution, do you mind sharing the code please?

Comment: I found that when using UIProgressView, the progress jumps from 0 to 1 at the end of the request and doesn't show actual progress. thats assuming the request is in a ASINetworkQueue